# Entities containing underscore character are split into multiple entities by TokensAnnotation in CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp, tokenize, penn-treebank

I am observing that coreNLP 3.9.2 has started splitting enti_ties into multiple ones like 'enti' , '_', 'ties' while tokenizing

I have tried to use the tokenize.whitespace which solves this problem. But I think this will stop splitting tokens for "cant't" and "dont't"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is replace the underscores (_) with a period (.) and the parser (and tokenizer, I believe) will interpret it as one entity.

E.g. `enti_ties` > `enti.ties` where the latter is retained as one entity

This doesn't entirely resolve the problem, but serves as a workaround in a pinch.